# how get torque of each joint during move in ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi !
how get torque of each joint  during move in ROS ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244137/how-get-torque-of-each-joint--during-move-in-ros-?/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2016-09-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is the plugin ft_sensor. Here's the snippet in my urdf file:

```
<xacro:macro name="sensor_force_torque" params="joint_name topic_name">
<gazebo>
  <plugin name="ft_sensor" filename="libgazebo_ros_ft_sensor.so">
    <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
    <topicName>${topic_name}</topicName>
    <jointName>${joint_name}</jointName>
  </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

</xacro:macro>

That's a macro so for creating instances it would be:

```
<xacro:sensor_force_torque joint_name="leg_1_joint_1"  topic_name="robot/leg_1_joint_ft_1"/>
```

I do get readings but I have not evaluated them properly but should give you a head start.

---

Originally posted by [wilsonz91](https://answers.ros.org/users/25250/wilsonz91/) with karma: 66 on 2016-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0